# Is there any app that would let me play Witcher 3 remotely?

Tags: game, cloud-service, streaming

I would like to play Witcher 3, but my PC GPU is way too slow for that. Is there an app that would let me play this game remotely, with the A/V streamed online?

Comment: For the money you would spend monthly, over 6 months for bandwidth that high you could just buy a r9 270x and play the game locally.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: I believe cloud gaming for such high profile games is not currently possible. Perhaps it will be in a few years time

---

While [Steam does offer a streaming service](http://store.steampowered.com/streaming/), it is meant to be used on local networks. [PlayStation Now also offers streaming services for PlayStation 3 games](https://www.gaikai.com/#!/playstation-now). However, trying to stream a high-end video game like Witcher 3 online would result in several setbacks due to the current state of technology.These include:

- **Video compression**: Streamed games won't have a high enough framerate or look as good as ones played locally
- **Bandwidth draining**: This applies especially if your ISP sets a quota on your bandwidth. Streaming video will take care of that in no time
- **Latency and visual feedback**: Your controls have to be transmitted online every time you press a button and the resulting video would have to be transmitted back many times every second. Unless you are very close to the server location, and have a super fast internet connection ([such as fiber](https://fiber.google.com/about/)), then it's highly unlikely that the game would be playable
- **Copyright laws**: For a service to stream playable video games online, they have to have the right to distribute the game. I also assume that would come with a subscription fee